# Kernel module load causes bug

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04, insmod, dmesg

i am new with kernel modules development and have decided to write my first kernel module today.

my module is supposed to receive 2 numbers as input, seperated by a whitespace and have those numbers added together.

the kernel module communicates via a proc entry named calc (/proc/calc), so reading from the file will be there returned output and writing to that file would be giving new input (2 numbers seperated by a whitespace)

when loading the module (insmod) my shell gets stuck, when interrupting it and looking at dmesg i see a kernel BUG line,
[here is the trace](https://gyazo.com/975dafee7d0e5996355a9f6d9f753064).

i am not sure if that is a bug in my code, or is it an actual bug at the linux kernel, and would love to understand what i've done wrong and how can i start debugging my module with the given dmesg log.

[here is the source code of my module](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U0AZdWDjegCpqsc1XOOohkClCCKW24ep).

my makefile is the very standard one,

```
obj-m += calc.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Many many thanks in advance!

EDIT: i am using ubuntu 16.04.02, release 4.10.0-28, quite standard.

Comment: According to Stack Overflow rules, the code of your driver and trace should be **in the question itself** as a text, not linked.

Comment: ok, didnt realise, thanks.
ill know better for next time

Answer (score 0):

Have you created device file ?

```
root@xyz-PC:~/s_flow/dd# ls -l /dev/my_device
```

if not then first create the device file using below command

```
root@achal:~/dd/char1# mknod /dev/my_device c  300  0
```

in my system(ubuntu 14.04) it's all good as below.

```
root@xyz:~/s_flow/dd# dmesg
[  519.751941] calc: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  519.752368] Calculator initializing
[  519.752372] Initializing proc entry at /proc/calc
[  519.752380] initialized calc proc entry
[  519.752384] mallocing last_message for 128 bytes
[  519.752386] malloc finished, resetting calc
[  519.752389] calc reset, all good :
```

can you give application program details which is using this module ?

Comment: i am not quite sure why is a nod required, care to explain?
p.s it did not help, but not i dont get any log in my dmesg

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the statement last_message = ""; is wrong.. You are assigning invalid memory address to pointer last_message. That's why OOPS is coming. last_message should be changed like this

```
static void reset_calc(void) {
    last_message_size = 0;
    last_message = "";
    last_message_type = WAS_LAST_READ; // we expect the first action to     be write
    }
```

should be changed to

```
   memset(last_message,0,MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
```